# Scala + Playframework + JClouds: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.inject.Provider field

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, scala-2.10, jclouds

In a larger playframework 2.1.3 application, I started to use JClouds blobstorage.
I added the dependencies

```
"org.apache.jclouds" % "jclouds-allblobstore" % "1.6.1-incubating",
"com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "1.3.+"
```

and added an action running the following code

```
val action = Action {
  val context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("s3")
    .endpoint("https://cs.hosteurope.de")
    .credentials(username, password)
    .buildView(classOf[BlobStoreContext])
  Ok("success")
}
```

When I run this action, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.inject.Provider field
```

In more detail, I get

```
[CreationException: Guice creation errors: 1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.inject.Provider field org.jclouds.blobstore.config.BlobStoreMapModule$BlobMapFactory.blobBuilders to com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4 at org.jclouds.blobstore.config.BlobStoreMapModule.configure(BlobStoreMapModule.java:50) while locating org.jclouds.blobstore.BlobMap$Factory Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.inject.Provider field org.jclouds.blobstore.config.BlobStoreMapModule$BlobMapFactory.blobBuilders to com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164) at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168) at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:680) at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:54) at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110) at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94) at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254) at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54) at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031) at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65) at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40) at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:204) at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024) at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198) at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:179) at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109) at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95) at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:405) at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:329) at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:620) at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:600) at controllers.admin.OtherController$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(OtherController.scala:40) at controllers.admin.OtherController$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(OtherController.scala:36) at controllers.admin.utils.MenuController$MenuAction.apply(Menu.scala:51) at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:108) at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:106) at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:106) at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:99) at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:137) at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1417) at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262) at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478) at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

To trace the problem, I created a completely new play app with the same library dependencies and then replaced the main action with the code above. That works perfectly well. And since I added all library dependencies of the large play app, I don't know what else in the larger app could break it.

What could cause that problem?

*edit:* Dependencies of the large app:

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25",
"org.squeryl" %% "squeryl" % "0.9.5-6",
"net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports"  % "4.7.1",
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M5b" % "test",
"jp.t2v" %% "play2.auth"      % "0.9",
"jp.t2v" %% "play2.auth.test" % "0.9" % "test",
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % "2.10.0"    % "test",
"com.unboundid" % "unboundid-ldapsdk" % "2.3.1",
"net.sf.uadetector" % "uadetector-resources" % "2013.06",
"org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.1",
"org.apache.jclouds" % "jclouds-allblobstore" % "1.6.1-incubating",
"com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "1.3.+"
```

Comment: How about "org.apache.jclouds" % "jclouds-core"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange, it works when I move the two dependencies

```
"org.apache.jclouds" % "jclouds-allblobstore" % "1.6.1-incubating",
"com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "1.3.+"
```

to the top of the list. When they are at the bottom, it doesn't work. So

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25",
"org.squeryl" %% "squeryl" % "0.9.5-6",
"net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports"  % "4.7.1",
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M5b" % "test",
"jp.t2v" %% "play2.auth"      % "0.9",
"jp.t2v" %% "play2.auth.test" % "0.9" % "test",
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % "2.10.0"    % "test",
"com.unboundid" % "unboundid-ldapsdk" % "2.3.1",
"net.sf.uadetector" % "uadetector-resources" % "2013.06",
"org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.1",
"org.apache.jclouds" % "jclouds-allblobstore" % "1.6.1-incubating",
"com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "1.3.+"
```

breaks, but

```
"org.apache.jclouds" % "jclouds-allblobstore" % "1.6.1-incubating",
"com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "1.3.+",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25",
"org.squeryl" %% "squeryl" % "0.9.5-6",
"net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports"  % "4.7.1",
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M5b" % "test",
"jp.t2v" %% "play2.auth"      % "0.9",
"jp.t2v" %% "play2.auth.test" % "0.9" % "test",
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % "2.10.0"    % "test",
"com.unboundid" % "unboundid-ldapsdk" % "2.3.1",
"net.sf.uadetector" % "uadetector-resources" % "2013.06",
"org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.1"
```

works.

Problem solved for me now. If anyone has ideas why order could be important though, I'd be curious.

Comment: The library uadetector-resources has a transitive dependency on 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1' like another dependency. Maybe there are some conflicts within your dependency tree that can be solved when using the right resolving strategy (or you find a solution by setting the transitives manually). It can help to create a detailed dependency report to find an appropriate solution.